# psql query to return values that contain space at the start/end of the value specified

Tags: whitespace, space, psql

I have a DB with more than 1,000,000 entries in it, some of them contain space char at the start/end of the value.

I have tried the following queries and it works but i would have to go through 1,000,000 records because all id's are unique

```
select * from tablename where id like '%1234%';
select * from tablename where id='1234 ';
select * from tablename where id=' 1234';
select * from tablename where id=' 1234 ';
```

is there a query that can be run that returns all values with space/empty char at the start/end of the value?

Appreciate your help
B

Comment: Do you have permission to clean the data?  That is the real solution!  Next fix the point of data entry to TRIM() on entry.  If that is not possible, add a constraint or trigger to the database to do it.

Comment: no, deleting records from DB is not an option, anyway I found the way to do this

select * from tablename where id like '% %';

Comment: I didn't say delete, just clean which is remove the spaces. Your solution will find embedded spaces as well. You had said you only wanted spaces at the beginning or end of the data.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a regular expression that says "one or more spaces at the start of the string OR one of more spaces at the end of the string".

```
select * from tablename where id ~ '^\s+|\s+$';
```

Each special character:

- ^ match start of the string
- \s match a white space character
- | the *or* operator
- + one or more times
- $ match the end of the string.

Answer (score -3):

I found the way to do this

```
select * from tablename where id like '% %';
```